# Project deployed to SSISDB no longer there

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I have a bit of a mystery on my hands...

I've been running a package in a project deployed to an SSIS server for several months. No changes in that time. Just a "somewhat" daily right-click the package and run it. Last time I ran it was yesterday. Last message in the executions report is from that time.

This morning, went to run the thing and it isn't there. Other than someone having deleted it, is there any way it could have vanished? If someone had deleted it, is there any way to find out who?

Comment: try to redeploy and see if it appears under SSIDB

Comment: It did redeploy with no problems and is working as it was. I'm just curious how it disappeared.

Comment: The source folder, was it still there or folder + project was deleted?

Comment: If I understand the question, the project folder in SSISDB was gone. In other words, the project that contained a single package is missing, project folder and all.

Answer (score 0):

Did somebody change your permissions?
Packages are only visible to sysadmins and users with ssis_admin role in SSISDB
Try to query the internal.Packages table in SSISDB to see if your packages are still there.